# Get Shopify Product Meta Description

Tags: shopify, liquid

In the Collection Template, I would like to add the Meta Description instead of the normal Product Description. I tried to replace **{{ product.description }}** with **{{ page_description | escape }}** but nothing is showing up. Do I need to add something like **{% for product in collection.products  %}** (doesn't work) around it?

Comment: Hi! Just to be clear, what you're trying to achieve is to replace, for each product in collection, their respective description by their meta description, right?

Comment: Hi @AliceGirard I want to show a short description below each product on the collection page. I made it work with {{ product.description }} but I would rather show the meta description so I can customize it better.

Comment: Unfortunately, meta description is not available in product object in Liquid (https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#product). The only way would be an ajax request for each product which will be a non optimized and really heavy solution. 

However, why would you not use a metafield instead of meta description to write a short description? This way you could access it anywhere with product object? This would be a better and optimized solution (and metafield are made to be used this way).

Comment: Thank you so much @AliceGirard I looked into metafields and managed to use this instead, great advice!